# How to get a thrown exception from MailerClient of Playframework

Tags: playframework-2.5

I'm working with [Play-Mailer](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer) inside of a Play application. I'm able to send emails to correct email addresses. So far so good. - But with none existing email addresses an exception is thrown from `org.apache.commons.mailer` but method `mailerClient.send(email)` itself throws nothing. - Is there a way to catch any exceptions form `Play-Mailer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I looked at the Play-Mailer plugin and saw that it is written in Scala. Scala does not have the notion of checked exceptions. Scala compiles directly to JVM bytecode and this is the "trick" how you can call Java code in Scala which throws checked exceptions but you do not have to rethrow them (the rules for checked exceptions are a bit different on JVM bytecode level).

You are free to use standard `try-catch` block in your Java code to handle the exceptions.

---

What kind of exceptions is the commons mailer throwing? Are you referring to: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html#send--

The `send()` methods throws an [EmailException](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/mail/EmailException.html) which is **not** a RuntimeException, so the exception would be propagated. If the Play-Mailer plugin is not catching it, you have to do it in your code:

```
try {
    // try to send the mail
    mailer.send(email);
} catch (EmailException e) {
    // do something with the exception
}
```

Comment: That's the way I do it. But IMHO that is not a clear way, to observe a method that doesn't throw a exception by declaration. Or am I wrong.

Comment: Look at my edited answer. Due to the fact that Play-Mailer is written in Scala there is some difference to how exceptions are declared and that is why the `try-catch` looks a bit strange

Comment: I guessed that as the problem too. Maybe only a `throws EmailException` in interface `MailerClient.java` would clarify the use of it. - Thank you for your answer.